# How to change ion-button size in Ionic 4?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm having trouble changing the size of my ion-button in Ionic 4. This same code used to work in the previous version, Ionic 3. I've modified my width and height of the button, but nothing works.

All that shows is the standard ion-button with an unchanged height/width.

page.scss

```css
.button {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-top: 27px;
   .login {
        font-family: $font;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        width: 280px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
}
```

page.html

```html
<div class="button"><ion-button class="login" (click)="login(oldUser)">LOGIN</ion-button></div>
```

Comment: We can help if you can post a demo of the code. Stackblitz maybe!

Comment: @ManojKumar I've looked into Stackblitz and it looks like they still have not updated their 'Ionic' editor to match Ionic 4's new layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find example on github for [custom buttons](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/button/test/standalone/index.html).

I can provide a snippet:

```
<ion-button class="round">rounded</ion-button>

    .round {
  --width: 60px;
  --height: 60px;
  --border-radius: 50%;
  --vertical-align: middle;
  --padding-start: 10px;
  --padding-end: 10px;
}
```

You can add it where you want in your app, this is done using CSS4.

If you plan on changing all `ion-button` consider doing so [globally](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/theme/variables.scss).

Check here for [Available custom control properties](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/core/src/components/button#css-custom-properties).

Comment: width and height are no longer variables : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-400-beta19-2018-12-14

Comment: This whole variables thing suck, it was the worst move that the Ionic team could've made

Answer (score -1):

```css
.button-class {
min-height: 5px !important;
}
```

This code worked for me, you can also fit this size to your needs